# Validating urls in a pandas dataframe column using validators module

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing urls which can has to be validated and obtain the resultant valid as list. The module used for validation of url is `validators` module.

Dataframe is like

```
pd.DataFrame({'url':['https://quotes.toscrape.com/','https://www.nashvillesymphony.org/','www.google.com']})
```

**Output Required**

```
['https://quotes.toscrape.com/','https://www.nashvillesymphony.org/']
```

Tried `data.loc[lambda data: validators.url(data.url) == True]` but getting an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following

```
results = [x for x in df["url"].values if validators.url(x) == True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
import validators
mask1 = df["url"].apply(validators.url) == True
df[mask1]
```

##### Output

|  | url |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | https://quotes.toscrape.com/ |
| 1 | https://www.nashvillesymphony.org/ |

Comment: Thanks. Please upvote the question too